# how to get all tag inside div tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to get tag value inside `DIV` tag using jquery

```html
<li class="a-carousel-card" style="width: 160px; margin-left: 14px;" role="listitem" aria-setsize="64" aria-posinset="1" aria-hidden="false">
   <div id="sp_detail_ABCDEF" data-asin="ABCDEC">                            </div>
</li>
```

i want to get value of div id and my output would be ABCDEF.

I tried

```
$("li[class$='a-carousel-card']").each(function(){

}
```

but i am not sure how can i get value.

Comment: Do you want the div's ID or its asin data attribute?

Comment: you have only one li item or many, pls paste your full li list

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you require you can use `this` within the `each()` loop to refer to each `li` being iterated over. Then you can use a combination of `find()` to retrieve the child `div` before using `data()` to get the `asin` value.

Also note that the 'attribute ends with' selector is not required in this case, as you can select by the class itself.

```js
$("li.a-carousel-card").each(function() {
  var divId = $(this).find('div').data('asin');
  console.log(divId);
});
```

```css
ul li {
  width: 160px;
  margin-left: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="a-carousel-card" role="listitem" aria-setsize="64" aria-posinset="1" aria-hidden="false">
    <div id="sp_detail_ABCDEF" data-asin="ABCDEC"> </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to looping each one, you can use `.map()` to get them all back at the same time (so depends on what format you need the result in).

```js
console.log($(".a-carousel-card>[id^=sp_detail]").map(function() {
    return $(this).data("asin");
}).get())
```

```css
li>div{ display:inline }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="a-carousel-card">
   <div id="sp_detail_ABCDEF" data-asin="ABCDEC">ABCDEC</div>
</li>
<li class="a-carousel-card">
   <div id="sp_detail_XYZ" data-asin="XYZ">XYZ</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this.
    $("li[class$='a-carousel-card'] div").data("asin");